# how does a user receive his own inputed data into his email when the user submits a form in react js

Tags: reactjs, forms, email, submit, form-submit

I have tried YouTube videos but what I keep seeing are videos of  EmailJS where the inputed form data were sent to the admin's email.

What I want is that a user will receive his own inputed data into his email when that user submits the form

I have tried YouTube videos but what I keep seeing are videos of  EmailJS where the inputed form data were sent to the admin's email.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do it in React.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export const App = () => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={(e) => setInputText(e.currentTarget.value)} />
      <a href={`mailto:user@email.com?body=${inputText}`}>Send Email</a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CodeSanbox link for complete code - https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-benz-5vsucj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks but, that would only open the email application in the browser.. what I need is that based on the users choices, the data selected by the user will be sent to the users email; for example, if the user checks bags, shoes and clothes in an e-commerce website, a link that shows the checked items should be sent to the users email when the submit button is clicked

Comment: If you want to send automated emails to users then in that case you need to use a mailing service like EmailJS.


Checkout the below article:
https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-emailjs-for-automated-emails-react-js-d0828165e2f